# Non-polynomial representations of double affine Hecke algebras?

Tags: representation-theory

I am a beginner in this area, I am getting familiar about polynomial representations of the double affine Hecke algebras of type $C^V_1 C_1$, and the relation between its spherical subalgebra to polynomial representations of the Askey-Wilson algebra. This article from Koornwinder is a good review to me: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612730.pdf.

I spent a lot of time trying to look for references about more exotic representations of these algebras, but I couldn't find anything.

My naive and general question is: if it really does not exist, why infinite dimensional, non polynomial representations of DAHA/Askey-Wilson have not been considered? What are the obstacles, and what kind of results would be interesting?

I apologize if my question is not precise, I would be glad to have any partial answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest type of representation to construct are induced representations. Because the DAHA $H$ has a triangular decomposition

$$H=R \otimes_\mathbf{Z} A$$

in which $R$ is a (Laurent) polynomial ring and $A$ is an affine Hecke algebra, by starting with an $A$-module $M$ you get an induced representation isomorphic (as a module over polynomials) to $R \otimes M.$ When $M$ is a one-dimensional representation of $A$, you get back the polynomial representation (or a minor variant).

There is a less explicit construction of the irreducible representations of $H$ in the $K$-theory of the affine Springer fibers, largely due to Vasserot and Varagnolo-Vasserot, in analogy to the way irreducible representations of the affine Hecke algebra may be realized using the Steinberg variety and Springer theory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is it true that these constructions concern finite dimensional representations of H? Do you know any reference about construction of infinite dimensional representations of H (if it exists)?

Comment: @Gropillon All of the induced representations $R \otimes M$, including the polynomial representation $R$ itself, are infinite dimensional, simply because $R$ is infinite dimensional. They do sometimes (upon specializing the parameters in $H$ appropriately) have finite dimensional quotients.